# Laguerre Polynomials in python

Tags: python

How do you print Laguerre polynomials in python?

I'm looking for something like 
`Laguerre(n,x)` which would give me the Laguerre polynomial L_n(x)

Comment: Stack overflow is not a replacement for proper research

Comment: @Mad Physicist I've searched a lot trust me. I haven't found a single good example of how to use Laguerre polynomials in python.

Comment: Given that the search "Laguerre Polynomial Python" immediately yields relevant results, I do in fact have a problem trusting you.

Answer (score 3):

Using Numpy ([Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html)):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Laguerre
p = Laguerre([1, -2, 1])
x = np.arange(5)
p(x)
```

Using scipy([Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.eval_legendre.html#scipy.special.eval_legendre)):

```
scipy.special.eval_genlaguerre(r_ord, phi_ord, float(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search leads to [`numpy.polynomial.laguerre.lagval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.laguerre.lagval.html#numpy.polynomial.laguerre.lagval). Example of usage:

```
np.polynomial.laguerre.lagval(x, np.eye(1, n+1, n)[0]) # L_n(x)
```

Comment: If I type `lagval(1,2)` it gives me 2.0, when it should be -1. So this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Turbotanten I have added an example of how to use `lagval`.